# autocomplete like google not able to get data on radiobutton event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have built a google search like option in my website and also included `Jquery UI Autocomplete` in the search box. 
I also have two `radio button`'s and on their `Checked` event that I am binding data source.

Like if `Company Name` radio button is checked I use `BindShipperName()` or if `Product Name` is checked I use `BindProductName()`. These bind functions are binding appropriate data source.

Following is the code for that:

```
if (rdoCompany.Checked){
  listFilter = BindShippmerName();
} else if (rdoProduct.Checked) {
  listFilter = BindProductName();
}
```

When I use the following script for auto complete it binds the appropriate data on `Checked` event, but by this I am not able to implement the search functionality fruitfully. What I do is just reflect the typed combination wherever it is there in the database search result. So this is wrong.

```
function LoadList() {        
  var ds=null;
  ds = <%=listFilter %>;
  $( "#txtConsignee" ).autocomplete({
    source: ds
  });
}
```

Then I added the following script to make it work, but its only binding data once on page load, `Product Name` is checked by default on page load, so it's only binding product name. If I click on `Company Name` Radio button then also its binding product name even I have assigned this `rdoCompany.Checked` to `listFinder`

My update script which is only binding `Product Name` is as follows:

```
function LoadList(){        
  var ds=null;
  ds = <%=listFilter %>;
  $( "#txtConsignee" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
      var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
      var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
      var a = $.grep( ds, function(item,index){
        return matcher.test(item);
      });
      responseFn( a );
    }
  });
}
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

C#

```
string names = "[" + BindShippmerName() + "," + BindProductName() + "]";
```

js

```
function LoadList()
{        
    var names = <%=listFilter %>;  //names will be now a js array of 2 elements
    var $rdoCompany = $('#<%=rdoCompany.ClientID %>');   //Get rdoCompany jquery obj
    var index = $rdoCompany.is(":checked") ? 0 : 1;   //Get selected in client side
    var ds = names[index]:      
    //From here, it's the same 
        $( "#txtConsignee" ).autocomplete({
              source: ds
        });
}
```

(If the above fails, try var `$rdoCompany = $('#<%=rdoCompany.ClientID %>' :radio);`, maybe my memory failed :) )

What we're doing is to get the selected option 'live', in javascript, so it's dynamic and doesn't get only the initial value.

Your problem was you only got the initial value, so it didn't work if it was changed.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @Edger nothing is working now. Not my text box is behaving like simple text box w/o autocomplete.

Comment: There can be an error in my answer, but do you understand my purpose in each line?

Comment: There is no error in your code the much i can find. Yeah i got it that what each line in doing.

Comment: Glad it helped you!. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia